# "{Registry Hive Recovered} Registry hive - was corrupted and it has been recovered"

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

I'm getting the following error showing up in my WIndows 7 PC.  Any ideas how what to do to resolve?

> {Registry Hive Recovered} Registry hive (file):
>   '\??\Volume{da160633-947a-11e0-b7f9-806e6f6e6963}\System Volume
>   Information\SPP\SppCbsHiveStore{cd42efe1-f6f1-427c-b004-033192c625a4}{71DBF2FE-968E-42E3-B3E5-913696155B59}'
>   was corrupted and it has been recovered. Some data might have been
>   lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you had/have some file corruption. I would try the following from an elevated command prompts where necessary:

1. Run `chkdsk /f /r`
2. Run `sfc /scannow`
3. Do a system restore to where your registry was not saying it is corrupt.

If none of that works, I would turn off System Restore, and then re-enable it as that might clean out any bad files in the System Volume Information directory, which is where the errors are being reported from. Immediately after, do a new system restore point.

Comment: thanks KCotreau - not at home at the moment but I'll try this - so just for my learning are you suggesting this corruption is only in the "windows restore" aspect of my system, hence it shouldn't be impacting day-to-day operation of Windows itself?

Comment: It could be elsewhere too, but that is what the error is reporting. Other areas may just not be verbose or have a mechanism to report it. In this case, your registry, being so important, is informing you.

Comment: @Greg Wow, glad that worked for you. I knew the answer made sense, but I was not too sure it would so it. If I may ask, what part actually did it for you?

Comment: sorry KCotreau - don't check this site very often & just noticed your comments now - unfortunately I don't remember exactly :(